# Yii2, how to work with the checkboxlist field

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

As I needed a checkbox list I decided to use the checkboxlist , but I cant seem to add the values into the DB, if im using the list it only stores the first value from the list instead of all checked checkboxes.

```
[['sort_abc'], 'string']//not working
[['sort_abc'], 'integer']//not working

<?=$form->field($model, 'sort_abc[]')->checkBoxLIst( ['1' => 'Item A', '2' => 'Item B', '3' => 'Item C'])->label($model->getAttributeLabel('sort_abc'));?>
```

DB field

```
sort_abc |  varchar(255) |  yes |   NULL
```

Also how can I add a image before every checkbox.

Comment: Sort _abc must be an array: $form->field($model, 'sort_abc[]')->checkboxList( ['1' => 'Item A', '2' => 'Item B', '3' => 'Item C'])->label($model->getAttributeLabel('sort_abc'));

Comment: For the second part of the question you have to work with css

Comment: Sorry forgot to add this in my example but already did this, still not working

Comment: ok show the controller code where you get the checkbox values please

Comment: I wonder what type in DB is your `sort_abc`. And in addition, it doesn't matter which rule you write for `sort_abc`, it should be loaded to the model (although it won't pass validation). If your `sort_abc` is string, then `beforeSave()` you have to encode it to something (like json), and decode on `afterFind()`

Answer (score 0):

Yii wont magically convert your array to string or (worse) integer. You may use virtual attributes defined by getters/setter to simplify whole thing:

```
public function getSortAbcArray() {
    if (empty($this->sort_abs)) {
        return [];
    }

    return explode(',', $this->sort_abc);
}

public function setSortAbcArray($value) {
    $this->sort_abs = implode(',', array_filter($value));
}
```

Then use this new attribute in form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'sortAbcArray')
    ->checkBoxList(['1' => 'Item A', '2' => 'Item B', '3' => 'Item C'])
    ->label($model->getAttributeLabel('sort_abc')); ?>
```

And in model rules:

```
['sortAbcArray', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']]
```

Then `$model->sortAbcArray` returns values as array and `$model->sort_abc` as string, where values are separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to name as array the field: `sort_abc[]` -> `sort_abc`

Simply doing it, the model will store in its attribute the checked checkboxes values.

To save the selected values, in your controller you can put:

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
if (count($post) > 0) {
    $post['YourModel']['sort_abc'] = implode(",", $post['YourModel']['sort_abc']);
}

if ($model->load($post) && $model->save()) {
    ...
}
```